# Typescript type of object literals of enum?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object, react-typescript

How to define type or interface for the below  object?

**here USER_TYPE is a enum**

```
type User = {
  [key in USER_TYPE]: { state: any };
};
```

***user object***

```
  const user: User = {
    [USER_TYPE.EMPLOYEE]: {state: { userPhoneNum: userPhoneNum } },
    [USER_TYPE.ADMIN]: {  state: { userData: userData } }
  };
```

```
return user[userType] // userType is same as enum defined
```

***userType enum***

```
export enum USER_TYPE {
  EMPLOYEE = "EMPLOYEE",
  ADMIN = "ADMIN"
}
```

***error*** is indicating in return

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'User'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'User'.ts(7053)
```

Comment: please provide full code

Comment: what exactly is `userType` here,it clearly state it's `any` which means you did something wrong with its type , I believe you can call it like `user[User_Type.ADMIN]`

Comment: @Yunhai i udpated above query pls look into USER_TYPE enum

Comment: @captain-yossarian  sorry i will not be able to provide that. my query is what how to define type for objects?

Comment: @Hitheshk Again, since your `userType` is an enum , then you have to use something like `user[userType.ADMIN]`, Unless userType is `"ADMIN"` string, then you can use `user[userType] `. You definitely can come out some minimal codes without any sensitive information for your problem.

Comment: @Yunhai  `userType` can either be `ADMIN` or `EMPLOYEE` based on the response.

Comment: @Hitheshk I have completely no idea what you are try to do, if user pass a `enum` into your function like this. `user[userType]` is literally a wrong way to try to get value. you either going to do something like `user["some string here"]` like user['ADMIN'] or user["EMPLOYEE"], but you try to pass a `enum` that maps to multiple values, which doesn't make any sense. You need to rethink your logic behinds the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SOLUTION***

This worked for me.

```
type User = {
  [key in string]: { state: any };
};
```